# Equivalent conditions for $f(n-o(f(n)))\sim f(n)$

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, discrete-mathematics, asymptotics

I'm working with non decreasing functions $f:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$ such that for any $g:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$ nondecreasing with
$$\frac{g(n)}{f(n)}\rightarrow0,$$ we have
$$\frac{f(n-g(n))}{f(n)}\rightarrow1.$$
So it seems like any f which is bounded linearly has this property, but I'm struggling to find a sufficient condition. Does anyone know of a simpler way of expressing this condition?

Comment: The title and body don't match. Is $g(n)$ supposed to be small relative to $f(n)$ or relative to $n$?

Comment: I fixed it, relatively small to $f(n)$.

Comment: (As stated, eventually constant functions $f$ satisfy the hypothesis vacuously; I suppose they're bounded linearly too, so that's fine.)

Comment: Certainly if $f(n)/n$ tends to infinity (however slowly), then just choosing $g(n)=n-1$ shows that $f$ doesn't satisfy the hypothesis. So the only case remaining open is $f$ such that $\limsup_{n\to\infty} f(n)/n = \infty$ but $\liminf_{n\to\infty} f(n)/n < \infty$.

Comment: @GregMartin Yeah makes sense, sadly in that last case I think it becomes very hard to make general statements.